# Oracle SQL -- select from two columns and combine into one

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have this table:

```
Vals
Val1  Val2  Score
A     B     1 
C           2
      D     3
```

I would like the output to be a single column that is the "superset" of the Vals1 and Val2 variable. It also keeps the "score" variable associated with that value.

The output should be:

```
Val Score
A   1
B   1
C   2
D   3
```

Selecting from this table twice and then unioning is absolutely not a possibility because producing it is very expensive. In addition I cannot use a with clause because this query uses one in a sub-query and for some reason Oracle doesn't support two with clauses.

I don't really care about how repeat values are dealt with, whatever is easiest/fastest.

How can I generate my appropriate output?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Can you use the `UNPIVOT` operator?

Comment: "and for some reason Oracle doesn't support two with clauses" --- it does, just specify them with comma and without `WITH` keyword

Comment: @zerkms the previous with clause is in a subquery

Comment: @Jeremy: move it to the top level then. I'm not even sure how nested `WITH` is possible

Comment: this have worked for me on 11.2 `WITH w AS(...) SELECT * FROM w, ( with...`

Comment: agree with zerkms - just bring all your with queries to the top level select.

Answer (score 9):

Here is solution without using unpivot.

```
with columns as (
  select level as colNum from dual connect by level <= 2
),
results as (
  select case colNum
              when 1 then Val1
              when 2 then Val2
            end Val,
         score
    from vals,
         columns
)
select * from results where val is not null
```

Here is essentially the same query without the WITH clause:

```
select case colNum
            when 1 then Val1
            when 2 then Val2
         end Val,
       score
  from vals,
       (select level as colNum from dual connect by level <= 2) columns
 where case colNum
            when 1 then Val1
            when 2 then Val2
         end is not null
```

Or a bit more concisely

```
select *
  from ( select case colNum
                     when 1 then Val1
                     when 2 then Val2
                  end Val,
                score
           from vals,
                (select level as colNum from dual connect by level <= 2) columns
        ) results
 where val is not null
```

Comment: Does Oracle support the WITH statement?

Comment: @PreetSangha - Oracle has supported WITH since Oracle 9i release 2

Comment: you can rewrite `where` in 2nd `select` like this: `(Val1 IS NOT NULL) OR (Val2 IS NOT NULL)`, or even shorter: `Coalesce(Val1, Val2) IS NOT NULL` ;)

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov - That won't give the correct result. For example, it won't weed out a Val1 null value if Val2 happens to be not null.

Comment: hmm, true. Not sure what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

try this, looks like you want to convert column values into rows

```
select val1, score from vals where val1 is not null
union 
select val2,score from vals where val2 is not null
```

Comment: union or union all?  the ops example doesn't make that clear.

Comment: from OP: `Selecting from this table twice and then unioning is absolutely not a possibility`

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Oracle 11, unPivot will help:

```
SELECT *
  FROM vals
UNPIVOT ( val FOR origin IN (val1, val2) )
```

you can choose any names instead of 'val' and 'origin'.

See [Oracle article on pivot / unPivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).